# pseudo elemenst not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

pseudo elements :after, :before not working in Firefox, but work perfectly in Chrome.

Can anyone explain how to fix it and why this occur:

[Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn979byy/)

HTML:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked>
```

CSS:

```
 .checkbox {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.375rem;
  margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 9px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.checkbox::before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 1.8rem;
  height: 1.8rem;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.checkbox:checked::before {
    border: 3px solid #CCCCCC;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  height: 0.9rem;

  border-color: #8ECA24;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
}

.checkbox::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.125rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 1.1rem;
  height: 1.1rem;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Looking at the linked question, I think Chrome may be doing something it shouldn't be in this instance. Firefox would appear to be working correctly by not outputting the pseudo element.

Comment: `:after` and `:before` are not supported on **form elements (inputs)** and **image elements**.